# I cant get a squaring program to work in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am very very new to node.js an I am trying to complete a simple program that squares a number. [This is what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBnYQ.png%60)

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

var stdin = '';
process.stdin.on('data', function (chunk) {
    stdin += chunk;
}).on('end', function() {
    var lines = stdin.split('\n');
    for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
        process.stdout.write("" +lines[i]*lines[i]);
    }
});`
```

The problem is that for my output, I am consistently getting a zero on the end. for example, if i put in 5, ill get 250 instead of 25. if i put in 25, ill get 6250 instead of 625. I don't know whats going wrong.

Comment: Hi, don't post screenshots of code, edit the question and post the code here, so everyone can help you. Once you do that I'll be happy to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stdin` will ad a newline whenever you submit a number, e.g.:

```
 5\n10\n
```

Now when you do this:

```
var lines = stdin.split('\n');
```

you will get:

```
["5", "10", ""]
```

So theres an empty line at the end. Now if you square that:

```
process.stdout.write("" * "");
```

It will print `0`.

---

Now to solve it remove the last element from lines:

```
 var lines = stdin.split('\n');
 lines.pop();
```

And you should consider printing a newline after every output:

```
 for(const line of lines)
   process.stdout.write(line ** 2 + "\n");
```